# Quantum teleportation of atomic states that involve energy

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, quantum-computer, quantum-teleportation

With quantum computing the concern is with information, and when quantum teleportation appears, the states being transferred are often spin states.

However, there is an energy difference, even if quite small, between spin up and spin down for a bound state.  If we quantum teleport such a state, are we locally violating conservation of energy?

I'm especially interested in theory papers which have considered this issue.

Comment: BTW, I am familiar with how quantum teleportation works for quantum information systems, though not an expert.

Comment: Here, on can argue that the ultimate state is set after a complex mixt protocol by a complex device with processing capacity. The question is relevant in a pure EPR experiment ( while there are many answers ).

Comment: How about measurement? Will it violate the conservation of energy? I believe the conservation of energy is a principle that should not be violated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conservation of energy in quantum teleportation](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/5942/)

Comment: I didn't ask if this is possible; I asked for papers which discuss this topic, and received the exact answer I was looking for.  When I look at the other questions they are similar, but have different purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This idea has been proposed, actually. There's even a wikipedia article about it. Keep in mind that it's controversial whether this works even in theory, and nothing has been done yet experimentally. But the wikipedia article leads to the relevant papers and ideas.

[Quantum energy teleportation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_energy_teleportation):

> Quantum energy teleportation is a [proposed] quantum protocol which transfers locally available energy [...] using local operations and classical communication (LOCC). [...] The transfer speed can be much faster than the velocity of energy diffusion of the system. It does not allow energy transportation at superluminal (faster than light) speed, nor does it increase total energy itself contained in a distant place.

Comment: This looks questionable (see also discussion page).

Comment: @NorbertSchuch True. It's only a proposed protocol, it hasn't been tried yet, and people disagree about it. But the wikipedia page talks about that. It's a very relevant resource to the question, even though it doesn't definitively answer the question. I could make that clearer in my answer.

Comment: If you are willing to read up on that and flesh out the essence of it, this would be very much appreciated.  (Also, it would make this an answer.)  It should be possible to explain this crisply -- then, it would also be possible to check correctness (which I doubt).  --- EDIT: To clarify, my doubts are on the theoretical protocol as such, not only on its experimental feasibility.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I don't have the requisite expertise to check the correctness of the proposed protocol, unfortunately. I just remembered that it existed, that it had a wiki article with references, and pointed that-a-way. I've pointed out the controversy in my answer.

Comment: http://blog.jessriedel.com/2014/02/04/literature-impression-hottas-quantum-energy-teleportation/ (Quote: *"The first thing to note is that this protocol would work just as good for classically correlated states as for quantum mechanically entangled states."*) -- EDIT: Also, note that from the blog post, it appears that you need a system with an entangled ground state (and thus a non-local interaction, if you consider just Alice's and Bob's system), which seems quite different from what the OP had in mind.